# Liquibase: setting searchPath for Java API

Tags: java, liquibase

In liquibase v4.13 you need to configure a "searchPath" to look up files, and I'm wondering the best way to achieve this when using the java API

Prior to v4, I could simply use this code and it worked

```
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);

liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```

which in latest version (was testing against v4.17.0 first, then increased to v4.19.0) resulted in the error

> The file path/to/changelog.xml was not found in the configured search path:
> More locations can be added with the 'searchPath' parameter.

So how should I configure "searchPath" here?

Tried this to same error result

```
Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
config.put("liquibase.searchPath", "/");

Scope.child(config, () -> {

  Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);

  liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```java
 new Liquibase(
                changeLofFile,
                new SearchPathResourceAccessor(getBasePath()),
                database);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).